# Tipo DateTime formato incorreto /Date(1566916268000)/ como resolver?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

O retorno do campo Dt_Inicio retornado do Banco de Dados está correto: `26/08/2019 11:08:10`

Porém no no javascript fica assim: `/Date(1566916268000)/`, veja:

```
$.each(response.listar, function (index, item) {
    console.log("item.Dt_Inicio: " + item.Dt_Inicio); <-- /Date(1566916268000)/
});
```

Tentei fazer essa conversão mas não funciona:

```
var _dt = new Date(item.Dt_Inicio.toLocaleString()); 
var dd = _dt.getDate();
var mm = _dt.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = _dt.getFullYear();

console.log("item.Dt_Inicio: " + dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy);

NaN/NaN/NaN
```

Comment: no seu console.log está retornando exatamente "Date(1566916268000)"? ou está retornando apenas o número "1566916268000"?

Comment: Olá! @Leonardo Getulio em meu console retorna /Date(1566916268000)/, porém encontrei a solução conforme indicado no alto do post, muito obrigado!